# Middleware getting called for error handling but not handling response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to handle errors by returning json, but my error handler (while being called, logs in console) wont return what I am trying to return. Here is the handler:

```
const handleError = function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(500);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

But I get returned a render function that translate to the following returned to me as the user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Invalid token with reason JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

So it will still log the error but unless I return an error in my actual function it wont return as intended, aka the following function does return a json error as written:

```
const view = function(req,  res, model, settings = {}, callback)  {
    let { params } = req;
    let { _id } = params;
    let { select, limit, sort } = settings;
    let query = model.findById(_id);
    if (select) query.select(select);
    if (sort) query.sort(sort);
    if (limit) query.limit(limit);
    query.exec(function(err, data) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(err,data);
        }else{
            if (err) return res.status(400).json({ 'Error': err.message });
            if (!data) return res.status(404).json({ 'Error': `No document with id ${_id} found` });
            return res.status(200).json(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is how I register my middlewares

```
let app = express();
app.server = http.createServer(app);

// logger
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// 3rd party middleware
app.use(cors({
    exposedHeaders: config.corsHeaders
}));

// Custom error handling 
app.use(api.handleError);

//Set body as json as recieved
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit : config.bodyLimit
}));
```

Comment: It means that default res.send() is being called before yours. Can you show registering of your middleware?

Comment: Sure, ill edit the post; but if that was the case wouldnt I get a 'trying to resubmit headers' type error? I had one recently for trying to send headers twice

Comment: Not sure. Also, is that rendered output raw (copied from network tab) or just browser's?

Comment: thats raw from postman (rest tool for testing api)

Comment: It looks like async issue. Do you call catch(next) or just next(error) in callback for all your async calls? Also register your error handler as last middleware else nothing after will be called.

Comment: I call next(err)

Comment: your `view` is not a *proper* express middlware, could you show how you're invoking it (or mounting it) and how you're calling `next`

Answer (score 0):

When I read the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) on error handling, it seems to me like you're *supposed* to `throw new Error()` (or call `next()`, depending on the sync/async nature of your handlers) in order to get the error handler working.

In your code above, I see you `return res.status().json()` -- which I don't think is the same thing.

You've pointed out that `unless I return an error in my actual function, it won't return as intended` -- so it sounds like you already know what's happening.

You also mentioned that `handleError` should return JSON -- why not change this:

```
res.status(500);
res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
```

...to...

```
res.status(500).json(error)
```

That should give you what you need.

Comment: Regardless of what I pass to that error handler, it wont handle it there but log still, ive tried several different ways to pass errors there

Answer (score 0):

Try to add error handler middleware bellow your route. Example:

```
app.get('/', indexHandler)
//call next(err) in indexHandler if there is an error
app.use(errorHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple
install express-async-errors
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors

```
run  npm install express-async-errors
```

and require it at the top of your app.js file

```
require('express-async-errors')
```